# How to stop creating new nested rows during loading

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I serialize/deserialize my data with marshmallow-sqlalchemy.

When I try to deserialize following data (Model2 with id=1 is present in the database, and id=2 is not) deserializer tries to create new row for id=2. How can I change this behaviour to add error if given models2 id is not present in the database?

Example input:

```
input = {
    "id": 1,
    "models2": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]
}
```

My models:

```
class Model1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'model1'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    models2 = relationship('Model2', secondary='Model1Model2', backref='models1')

class Model1Model2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'model1_model2'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    model1_id = db.Column(Integer, ForeignKey('model1.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    model2_id = db.Column(Integer, ForeignKey('model2.id'))

class Model2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'model2'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

My schemas:

```
class BaseSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        sqla_session = SESSION


class Model2Schema(BaseSchema):
    class Meta(BaseSchema.Meta):
        model = Model2
        dump_only = ('name',)


class Model1Schema(BaseSchema):
    class Meta(BaseSchema.Meta):
        model = Model1
        fields = ('id', 'name')

    models2 = Nested(Model2Schema, many=True, only=('id'))
```